# add-apt-repository sets incorrect distribution name

Tags: kde

I am using KDE Neon's test images which appear to be based off Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial as `lsb_release -a` definitely returns that. When I try to use the `add-apt-repository` command it asks me to install `software-properties-common` which I do.

Once installed, every time I try to add a new repository, the repository does get added but instead of using `xenial` as a reference for a distribution name, it sets `yakkety`. Due to this, of course, `apt-get` fails to find any packages. The fix is to manually change the `yakkety` reference to `xenial`.

`lsb_relase -a` returns

```
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon Developer Edition
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

How do I fix it please? I don't understand where it pulls the incorrect distribution reference from. I hope I can just change an ASCII file to change the setting.

For your reference, the ISO I am currently testing is [here](http://files.kde.org/neon/images/neon-devedition-gitunstable/current/neon-devedition-gitunstable-20160521-0806-amd64.iso)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!! All I had to do is edit **/etc/lsb-release** from:

```
Distributor ID: neon
Description:    KDE neon Developer Edition
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

to

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Voila! Problem went away. Who would have thought? While troubleshooting this, I was specifically focusing on the Codename parameter returned by the **"lsb_relase -a"** which clearly states "**xenial**" so I could not understand why it kept referencing "yakkety" instead.

It appears as if the "**aptsources.distro.get_distro()**" method used throughout the **add-apt-repository** script does not necessarily read the distribution codename from the Codename parameter in **/etc/lsb-release** but somehow it works it out by reading "**Distribution ID**". I think the key here is the **"Distribution ID"** saying "neon". Because if you read "**/usr/share/distro-info/ubuntu.csv**" you will see this:

```
version,codename,series,created,release,eol,eol-server
4.10,Warty Warthog,warty,2004-03-05,2004-10-20,2006-04-30
5.04,Hoary Hedgehog,hoary,2004-10-20,2005-04-08,2006-10-31
5.10,Breezy Badger,breezy,2005-04-08,2005-10-12,2007-04-13
6.06 LTS,Dapper Drake,dapper,2005-10-12,2006-06-01,2009-07-14,2011-06-01
6.10,Edgy Eft,edgy,2006-06-01,2006-10-26,2008-04-25
7.04,Feisty Fawn,feisty,2006-10-26,2007-04-19,2008-10-19
7.10,Gutsy Gibbon,gutsy,2007-04-19,2007-10-18,2009-04-18
8.04 LTS,Hardy Heron,hardy,2007-10-18,2008-04-24,2011-05-12,2013-05-09
8.10,Intrepid Ibex,intrepid,2008-04-24,2008-10-30,2010-04-30
9.04,Jaunty Jackalope,jaunty,2008-10-30,2009-04-23,2010-10-23
9.10,Karmic Koala,karmic,2009-04-23,2009-10-29,2011-04-29
10.04 LTS,Lucid Lynx,lucid,2009-10-29,2010-04-29,2013-05-09,2015-04-29
10.10,Maverick Meerkat,maverick,2010-04-29,2010-10-10,2012-04-10
11.04,Natty Narwhal,natty,2010-10-10,2011-04-28,2012-10-28
11.10,Oneiric Ocelot,oneiric,2011-04-28,2011-10-13,2013-05-09
12.04 LTS,Precise Pangolin,precise,2011-10-13,2012-04-26,2017-04-26
12.10,Quantal Quetzal,quantal,2012-04-26,2012-10-18,2014-05-16
13.04,Raring Ringtail,raring,2012-10-18,2013-04-25,2014-01-27
13.10,Saucy Salamander,saucy,2013-04-25,2013-10-17,2014-07-17
14.04 LTS,Trusty Tahr,trusty,2013-10-17,2014-04-17,2019-04-17
14.10,Utopic Unicorn,utopic,2014-04-17,2014-10-23,2015-07-23
15.04,Vivid Vervet,vivid,2014-10-23,2015-04-23,2016-01-23
15.10,Wily Werewolf,wily,2015-04-23,2015-10-22,2016-07-22
16.04 LTS,Xenial Xerus,xenial,2015-10-22,2016-04-21,2021-04-21
16.10,Yakkety Yak,yakkety,2016-04-21,2016-10-20,2017-07-20
```

So *I guess* if aptsources.distro.get_distro() fails to find a "known and official" distribution ID then it just reads this file "as a last resort by default and if everything else fails" to retrieve the latest "known" name which in this case is "yakkety". Anyway, it may not necessarily work this way but what I changed definitely resolves the issue I had.